# Why can't a nullable int as string be null in c#?

Tags: c#

For some reason unknown `visualstudio` tells me this code is unreachable:

```
            int? newInt = null;
            string test = newInt.ToString();
            if (test == null)
            {
                //unreachable Code
            }
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Try running it and see what `test` is set to.  However if you did `newInt?.ToString()` then `test` would be `null`.  In fact you might ask why it doesn't throw a null reference exception, which is a bit more interesting.

Comment: use  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))  instead

Comment: The documentation for [`Nullable<T>.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it returns an empty string if `HasValue` is `false` (which is the case when you set a `Nullable<T>` to `null`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string test = newInt.ToString();
```

test will never be null if you convert it to `string`. when you convert it, it will become empty string.

```
int? newInt = null;
string test = newInt.ToString();
if (test == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); //Reaches the code
    }
```

Comment: if you do `int? intNex = new int();` then it will be `0`

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari You're not *casting* it to a string.  You're calling a method, `ToString`, and that method can do whatever it wants in its implementation.  `Nullable` happens to choose to print an empty string when it doesn't have a value.

Comment: @Servy, you cannot cast from `int` or `int?` to `string`.

Comment: @Prajwal Try it and find out for yourself.

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari I know that you can't cast an `int` to a string.  That's why I told you that you can't cast an `int` to a `string` in my first comment, when you claimed that the `int?` was being cast to a `string`.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

`((int?)null).ToString() == string.Empty`

The return value from a nullable int is an empty string. The code in the if block is indeed checking for a null value that could never exist. This only works because `int?` is a framework type, and the behaviour of `ToString()` is known and immutable. If you tried this on a user-defined value type, the same assertion could not be made.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int? i = null;

    var str = i.ToString();

    int? j = null;

    var str2 = j?.ToString();
```

In the above code, str will be the empty string and str2 will be null.  By using the ?. operator on j, we can get a null value instead of the empty string for str2.  This is a workaround that provides a more intuitive string conversion and would make the OP code reachable.

Answer (score -1):

`.ToString()` cannot allow null value.

You can use:

```
 convert.ToString(newInt)
```

Check condition by:

```
 "string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))"
```

Comment: It *can*.  It *doesn't*.  There's nothing stopping it from returning `null` if the designers had decided that that's what they wanted to do.